# Storing amounts per VAT percentage

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app with invoices. For an invoice it shows the invoice lines with an amount and VAT percentage. In the summary of the invoice I need to show the total VAT amounts grouped per VAT percentage. An invoice_line record has a rate, quatity and vat_id. So when showing the invoice lines I iterate through them and show them:

```
- @invoice.invoice_lines.each do |line|
  %td= line.rate
  %td= line.quanity
  %td= line.rate*line.quantity
  %td= Vat.find(line.vat_id).percentage
```

How can I store the amounts grouped per VAT ID? I thought of storing them in an array with hashes, but that gets complicated and maybe there is a good alternative I'm overlooking?

Edit:
I think I found a way using a Hash. First I iterate all VAT records and creating the Hash:

```
    - vat_amounts = Hash.new
    - @vats.each do |vat|
      - vat_amounts[vat.percentage] = 0
```

And then, when iterating the `invoice_lines`, I add the VAT amount to the proper Hash record:

```
        - invoice.invoice_lines.each do |line|
          - vat = Vat.find(line.vat_id)
          %tr
            %td= line.quantity
            %td= line.rate)
            %td= line.quantity*line.rate
            %td= vat.percentage
            - vat_amount = (line.quantity*line.rate)*vat.percentage
            - vat_amounts[vat.percentage] += vat_amount
```

And finally, when creating the summary, I show the total VAT amounts per VAT percentage:

```
  .summary
    - total_vat = 0
    - @vats.order(:percentage).each do |vat|
      = "VAT #{vat.percentage}:" 
      = vat_amounts[vat.percentage]
```

Of course, a lot of improvements to be made, but this seems to work.

Comment: When you say "grouped by vat percentage", you mean the `invoice_lines`?

Comment: yes, grouped by invoice_lines vat_id

Comment: Hmm let me write an answer

Comment: Actually - what are you trying to do exactly? Grouping per VAT ID will only being back single records per VAT ID?